# Looking for a irrigation system leak sensor? Is there such a thing?

Tags: irrigation

I have an Orbit Wifi B-hyve controller and a three zones manifold.
I am looking for a way to determine if the water flows through the irrigation system when it should not (ex one of the valves fails or there is a crack in the system and the water leaks through that)
I am not very comfortable with the idea that I will have PVC in the ground parallel with my house. This could leak and cause a basement flood before I get to know (I night time leak or while I am away could be disastrous not for the amount of water wasted but for water leaking into the basement (old house -might have foundation cracks I do not know about)
What is a standard solution in situations like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a main solenoid valve and measure the pressure between that and the manifold, much less work then a sensitive flow sensor. Turn the manifold valves off then the main and monitor the pressure to the manifold. This could be connected to the pump output of the sprinkler controller for normal operation. This does give you redundancy so the main and one other valve have to fail.

Comment: Yes that would work but I am not clear on how the controller would handle two things at once. Apparently it can not fire up two zones at the same time. Not sure how the pump output is activated. There is also this solution that I found after posting here Gowfeel WiFi Smart Valve WiFi Control Water Valve Compatible with Alexa, Google and Application Program iOS/Android https://a.co/d/dzZLrYB

Comment: after reading it again, I am seeing that the manual says that circuit is turned on every time B-Hyve is active (that is when another valve is active) so I guess that will do it
Now I have a challenge and that is to feed that valve from the 5 wires cable run that goes  to the 3 valves I have and which runs close to the tap where the main control valve will be placed

Answer (score 1):

You could use an inline flow meter